# How to get Wordpress to "notify changes" to a WebService/Uri

Tags: wordpress

We are building a fairly dynamic platform with several functions and a wide dynamic of technologies (F#, C#, MVC, Python, etc).  For the CMS/Content, we have elected to use Wordpress to cut down on development time.  And, "it is so pretty and functional as-is" -CEO.

The challenge: How to get Wordpress to notify an external service/uri that something has changed.

**We do not want to write "background threads" from the other services to constantly "ping" the wordpress site/database for changes, aka "Pull".**  We want this to be a Push model.

With that said, we are looking to pass some json, xml, or something to another url that we can consume the changes and handle internally.

SQL Azure does support triggers, yes; but, did you shudder as much as I did when you read the word "triggers"?  Besides, I wouldn't have a clue where to start on what tables for them.

Here are a few changes we'd like to capture:

- Post Drafts
- Post Published
- Post Deleted (and so on)
- Tag added, renamed, deleted
- Category added, renamed, deleted

And possibly other event such as when a media file gets uploaded (for the CDN).

Random -almost related- thought: I have found some Wordpress plugins for Windows Azure Blog Storage for media, which may help - I'll try to setup a Storage account for the CDN for the media stuff.  If there are other related Wordpress plugins for notifying external services for categories, tags, etc, please let me know - I haven't found them (they all just "email" someone).

I found questions such as this:

[Wordpress: How to ping URL from custom field on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093772/wordpress-how-to-ping-url-from-custom-field-on-publish)

But it doesn't get me all the way there for all post drafts (I think).  And, I'm not even sure where to insert that code (haven't modified a wordpress install before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is [create a Wordpress plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). That way, your code is separate from both the Wordpress Core and the chosen theme.

The plugin could be pretty simple. You'll need one or more functions to do the notifying, and a bunch of `add_action` statements for the [action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to fire a function when that action of interest occurs.

```
function so23600027_notify_external_site( $post_id ) {
    //Your notification code here, probably using cURL
}

// Catch when posts saved (should get both draft and published posts)
add_action ( 'save_post', 'so23600027_notify_external_site' );

//Catch when posts deleted
add_action ( 'delete_post', 'so23600027_notify_external_site' );

//etc.
```

Comment: Yep, thats is what im thinking. But, Will plugins capture the actions of other data types? Categories, Tags, etc?  Guess it is time to go dig into WordPress plugin api.

Comment: +1 and marked as answer. I found and edited your answer to include a link to the actions - which shows everything.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, take a look at the link on "action hooks" above for posts and categories. Tags are a different story.